# Find the width/height of a triangle given a side length and two lines

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm a programmer and I came across a math problem in my current project that I can't figure out.

My situation looks like this.

[image]

Everything in black is known or I know how to figure out.

- `A` and `B` are the two lines of which their equations are known.
- `h` is the length of the side between the two lines
- `w` is the width of the triangle
- `I` is the point where the two lines intersect

And I want to figure out the value of `w`

It's worth mentioning that my triangle can be any kind of triangle, not just isosceles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call your two equations $f(x)=Ax+B$ (the upper one) and $g(x)=Cx+D$.

For exactly the right $x=x_h$ they are $h$ apart. We then have $$f(x_h)-h=g(x_h)$$
from which $x_h$ can be isolated.

At their intercept, with $x=x_I$ we have $f(x_I)=g(x_I)$, from which we can isolate $x_I$.

Then $$x_I-x_h=w$$

Comment: How do I go about finding the other side lengths?

Comment: @SpaceFace Do you know the $x$-position of the line $h$?

Comment: No, that's essentially what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @SpaceFace See my new answer; was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I actually just came up with the same thing on my own a few moments ago, I might give my own answer with a bit more detall, but I'll mark this.